# Smooth way to repeat DOM elements

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm interested in getting an array of identical (though distinct or cloned) DOM elements so I can use them like this:

```
parentElement.append(...arrayOfRepeatingElements);
```

The best I've come up with is:

```
[0,0,0].map(() => document.createElement('br'))
```

Or for larger numbers:

```
new Array(100).fill(0).map(() => document.createElement('br'))
```

Or slightly shorter:

```
[...'0'.repeat(100)].map(() => document.createElement('br'))
```

Is there an even cleaner/more semantic yet DRY and inlinable-as-an-expression way of doing this?

Comment: Maybe this `Array.from({length: 100}, _=> document.createElement('br'))` ?

Comment: <br> is deprecated

Comment: @user7951676 Since when...?

Comment: `<br>` is not deprecated. It's officially supported in HTML5. Why would anyone deprecate that? It's useful to a lot of developers. The only issues that can arise is from CSS.

Comment: Since before 2000

Comment: @user7951676 : I guess you might be looking at old XHTML docs that were trying to deprecate `<br>` with `<line>`... No mention of deprecation at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element

Comment: Yeah seams I was wrong though I'm sure I saw it on mdn a while back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array#from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
var parentElement = document.getElementById('parentElement');
var elements = Array.from({length: 100}, _=> document.createElement('br'));
parentElement.append(...elements);
```

```html
<div id='parentElement'></div>
```

Comment: Glad I stuck around for this! Never knew about this method nor it's capabilities til now. Awesome.

Comment: Yeah, quite clever--Still wish there was a `.repeat()` method as with strings but nice to do it in a single call...